# Как сделать для Combobox SCROLL?

Tags: c++, combobox

Мне нужно сделать  для Combobox SCROLL,  но я  не  нашел. Для едита есть ES_AUTOVSCROLL,  а от  для  Combobox  нету. Как  тогда сделать SCROLL?

Answer (score 1):

Вертикальная прокрутка для COMBOBOX появляется автоматически, когда количество элементов в списке не помещается в текущую высоту списка. Если помещаются - то прокрутка не отображается. Если при создании COMBOBOX укажем стиль CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL, то прокрутка будет отображаться постоянно, но отключенная или включенная (в зависимости от количества элементов). Для автоматического отображения горизонтальной прокрутки указываем стиль CBS_AUTOHSCROLL.

Comment: Да  есть . я  не  знал что она есть. справа просто нету ползунка.